# Classes that inherit from interfaces but implement additional methods in UML diagram

Tags: class, inheritance, interface, uml, class-diagram

I have to do an UML class diagram for a project in which I implement an interface with abstract methods for RL algorithms. I implement several algorithms that implement an interface but implement additional methods depending on the algorithm. How can I capture that in an UML diagram? I have thought in including a box with the generic name "Algorithm" and the attributes and methods
"Algorithm specific attributes/methods", would that be correct in the UML framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class should not inherit an interface but realize (aka implements) it. Graphically, you'll use the same notation than inheritance but with a dashed line:

[image]

Your case is a classic case of interface realization, as you'll find for example in a [strategy pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).  The fact that you add other operations (aka methods) is completely normal and does not require anything special.

If you're using abstract classes instead of interfaces, then you may use inheritance:

[image]

Comment: An interface is a metaclass denoted by the keyword «interface». Generalization inherits features (p. 136). But it does inherit the metaclass. So it stays what it is. However, a class can inherit from an interface. Whether that's useful probably depends?

Comment: @qwerty_so Interesting. I was more concerned about usefulness and ambiguity. Usually interfaces inherit from other interfaces and classes from classes. I understand that a class could inherit from an interface, but what would it mean? For example, what would be the semantic of a class that inherits from an interface but does not implement all the interface’s operations?

Comment: Yep. That's also my final question mark...

Comment: @qwerty_so I updated the wording to use "should not" instead of "does not", to reflect your comment, and in the meaning of [RFC 2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119).